# How to print the character with the maximum occurrence in the string

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to print the character with the maximum number of occurrences in a user given string. However, when it prints the output, it prints the counter correctly, but the character is just a question mark with a box. It does not print the char correctly.

### Output is this:

### Find the maximum occurring character in a string

Enter a string: test string
The highest frequency of character '' appears number of times is 3

### It should be:

### Find the maximum occurring character in a string

Enter a string: test string
The highest frequency of character 't' appears number of times is 3

How can I get rid of

This is my current code. I am new to assembly so please help me out.

```
%include "asm_io.inc"

section .data
    dash                db "-------------------------------------------------", 0
    progTitle           db "Find the maximum occurring character in a string", 0
    enter_string_prompt db "Enter a string: ", 0
    output_format       db "The highest frequency of character '%c' appears number of times is %d",0

section .bss
    string_length       resb 100
    input_string        resb 256
    max_char            resb 1
    max_count           resd 1
    counts              resb 256     ; will store the count of the characters

section .text
    extern printf, fgets, stdin
    global asm_main

asm_main:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, dash
    call print_string
    call print_nl
    mov eax, progTitle
    call print_string
    call print_nl
    mov eax, dash
    call print_string

    call print_nl

    ; prompt
    mov eax, enter_string_prompt
    call print_string

    push dword [stdin]
    push string_length
    push input_string
    call fgets
    add esp, 12

    mov esi, input_string

count_loop:

    movzx eax, byte [esi]
    cmp al, 0
    je end_count_loop

    ; Skip counting spaces
    cmp al, ' '
    je skip_increment

    inc byte [counts + eax * 4]

skip_increment:
    inc esi
    jmp count_loop

end_count_loop:
    mov ecx, 256
    mov edi, counts
    mov eax, [edi] ; Initialize eax with the first count

find_max_loop:
    cmp dword [edi], eax
    jl next_char

    ; Update max_char and max_count
    mov eax, [edi]
    mov[max_char], al
    mov dword [max_count], eax

next_char:
    add edi, 4
    loop find_max_loop


    movzx eax, byte[max_char]
    push eax
    push dword [max_count]
    push output_format
    call printf
    add esp, 12

    call print_nl

    leave
    ret
```

Comment: I don't see where `esi` is being initialized.  Also, you're treating `counts` as byte array in one place yet as word in another.

Comment: `inc byte [counts + eax * 4]` looks wrong.  Your `counts` is an array of bytes, not dwords, so the index shouldn't be scaled.  Actually, the rest of your code is doing 4-byte loads from it to look for a `max`, so probably you should just change it to `resd 256` instead of `resb 256`, and use `dword` operand-size for the increment.

Comment: `counts resb 256` should be `resd` because you seem to use dwords everywhere in the code. `mov[max_char], al` is nonsense, since `al` is the low 8 bits of `eax` which holds the count. Also during printing you push the operands in the wrong order.

Comment: esi is where the input string is